# Is it possible to use bootstrap 4 in a nextjs project by just adding a link stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, next.js

I have this project where I imported bootstrap like this on my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Everything was working fine until I decided to add a carousel.
The carousel shows up properly, but it doesn't rotate and the buttons on the side doesn't work.
I also noticed that my colapsed menu also don't work.

On my research I saw a lot of people suggesting to use reactstrap and some other third party libraries, but I'm wondering if it's possible keep using the link stylesheet.

From what I read the problem is with the jquery and bootstrap being imported in the wrong order, which might cause those elements to break.

Comment: I'm using reactstrap and I'm linking the global stylesheet (in my global SCSS but that's the same in the end). The problem with the carousel is that it needs JS to be dynamic and Bootstrap uses jQuery, Popper.js and its own JS which doesn't play well out of the box with React. Reactstrap then becomes a good alternative.

Comment: Hello @EmileBergeron, thank you for your answer! I just found the solution for the problem I had and it worked just fine. I didn't had to install any of the other libraries and just added the bootstrap.js and jquery as well in the right order.

Answer (score 4):

Solved the issue using another website as reference:
https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Instead of using

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

I used

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

And it is finally working.

Answer (score 0):

> but it doesn't rotate and the buttons on the side doesn't work. I also noticed that my colapsed menu also don't work.

there is no functionality on your pages if dont import the js scripts.
**add these scripts also and your buttons and collapse menu should start working**

```
**for css link**
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```